# Is dark matter expanding the universe, and creating the structures within it?

Tags: universe, dark-matter, space-expansion

If dark matter repelled other dark matter, as well as regular matter(atomic or celestial), and regular matter were repelled by other regular matter "less" than by the dark matter, would not this result in the coalescence of regular matter into spheres? And if so, and given the repulsive force of dark matter on regular matter is equal to the attractive strength of gravity.  Could the influence of that dark matter on those spheres, be equivalent to, but opposite, the pull of gravity, thus eliminating gravity altogether from the equation?

Just a hypothetical I've been pondering. Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The dark matter is known (from galactic rotation curves and microlensing) to clump around galaxies and to mass considerably more than the visible matter.

This contradicts your hypothesis, so no.